# Wordpress: blank pages and when i refresh the permalinks setting it works

Tags: wordpress

Please sometimes all pages are blank pages in my website only the home page and the admin side IDK why but when i refresh the permalinks setting it works.
any one can help me to resolve this problem please

Comment: Make a Backup of these files/dir: wp-content, wp-config.php
Delete all and include the backup files. Then try it again.
And take a look into the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually an issue in the .htaccess from when you have setup your permalinks.

if you are using the postname for your permalinks make sure this code is at the top of the .htaccess.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```